# What is a trick for remembering the order of arguments to a comparator function?

Tags: javascript, sorting, comparison, comparison-operators

In javascript ( or many other languages ), there is a method like Array.prototype.sort.  It takes an argument which is a function like the following one:

```
 array.sort( compare )
```

Suppose I want to sort the array in ascending order.  I have a very hard time remembering if that function is supposed to look like this:

```
 array.sort( function compare(a,b){
     if ( a < b ){ return -1 }
     if ( a > b ){ return 1 }
     return 0;
 })
```

or like this

```
 array.sort( function compare(a,b){
     if ( a < b ){ return 1 }  // NOTE that -1 and 1 are swapped here!
     if ( a > b ){ return -1 }
     return 0;
 })
```

I get tired of googling this all the time.  Is there a trick or mnemonic for remembering it?

Comment: I deduce it from the standard number comparison `(a, b) => a-b` when I need it.

Answer (score 3):

The rule: **For sorting in ascending order, if the first parameter of the compare function is bigger, return 1.**

The key words here are "ascending", "first", "bigger" and "1". In each case, think of what is "better":

- **"Ascending" is better.** *Think of "climbing the ladder" and "rising to the challenge".*
- **"First" is better.** *Think "first in line" and "first place".*
- **"Bigger" is better.** *That cliche already exists. 'Nuff said.*
- **"Positive" is better.** *Think "positive attitudes" and "positive outcomes". (Alternatively, "plus" is also better. Think "that's a big plus".)*

Then you can think of the following as you write your code:

```js
var array = [3,2,1,2];

document.write('unsorted array: ' + array + '</br>');

var POSITIVE =  1;
var SAME     =  0;
var NEGATIVE = -1;

array.sort(function compare(firstParam, secondParam) {

  var theyAreTheSame = (firstParam === secondParam);
  // that shouldn't require any memory aid

  var firstIsBigger  = (firstParam  >  secondParam);

  if      (theyAreTheSame) return SAME
  else if (firstIsBigger ) return POSITIVE // the key line
  else                     return NEGATIVE;

});

document.write('sorted array: ' + array);
```

This leads to the following:

- To sort in the better order (i.e. the ascending one)...
- ...if the better parameter (i.e. the first one)...
- ...is the better relative size (i.e. bigger)...
- ...then the better value (i.e. the positive one) should be returned from the compare function.

*(Disclaimer: I make no claims about the utility of this memory aid for other languages or even other functions, but, hey, hopefully it helps someone with Javascript's array sort!)*

**Update**: Fixed the code by replacing 'let' and 'const' with 'var' (i.e. reverting from ES6 to ES5 for variable declarations) so that the code not only works in Firefox but also in Chrome and Safari. (I haven't checked Internet Explorer or other browsers.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm suffering the same for a very very long time, but this ends now .. at least let me try :)

Let's forget about the built-in [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) for a sec, and let's skip through this Bubble Sorting algorithm:

```
function bubbleSort(arr, comparator) {
    let len = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
            // If the comparator function returns a positive number, it means arr[j] > arr[j + 1]
            if (comparator(arr[j], arr[j + 1]) > 0) {
                // Swap arr[j] and arr[j + 1]
                let temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}

let numbers = [40, 1, 5, 200];
bubbleSort(numbers, (a, b) => a - b); // sorts the array numerically and ascending
console.log(numbers); // [1, 5, 40, 200]
```

### Did you notice something?

- Only **Positive** value was considered .. when **Positive** .. then Do your action .. Do the **Swapping**

### Now the important part:

For something like `(a, b)` .. **Return positive when you need to do the swapping**

If you need **Bigger** first

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a < b) {
    return 1 // Positive: Do your action .. Do the Swapping
  }
  // else ...
})
```

which means:

- `a` is the current **First**

  - If `a` is small ..

    - Then return **Positive** to do the **Swapping** .. because we need **First** to be **Bigger**